# insert ignore won't ignore

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, exists

This code: would **allways** insert the Row, never detect that exists

```
$r =  mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO facebook (uid,fid) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','".$persone['id']."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

why?

Edit: Please not, the input vales are allways the same

Comment: What is primary key on `facebook` table? `INSERT IGNORE` checks for primary key only.

Comment: i see.. so how can i turn uid as primary key? @Kosta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT IGNORE` works on primary key fields only. If your `facebook` table does not have primary key set, you can do it like this:

```
alter table facebook add primary key (uid)
```

After this, `INSERT IGNORE` won't insert duplicated lines.

Comment: The problem i think is that i don't want to prevent duplicate key but duplicate combination (or row)

Comment: Then you can put both columns into primary key with `ALTER TABLE facebook ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid, fid)`, or check if row exists before inserting new row. Note that if you already have primary key defined, you need to drop that key first with `ALTER TABLE facebook
DROP PRIMARY KEY` and then add new primary key.

Comment: The following errors were reported:Multiple primary key defined

Comment: Like I said, you need to drop previous primary key with the code I wrote and then add primary key again.